# A small bug using markdown with links in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170815/string-reversal-complexity#comment50350280_31170959) I wrote a comment with markdown:

```
This is roughly true, but the actual conditions are "(1)one-char String and
this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\",
or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is
not the ascii digit or ascii letter." ([source]
(http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk
/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29))
```

This seems to be rendered like

[image]

When it really should make only the word "source" a link.

The problem doesn't seem to exist in answers or questions, just in comments. In questions only the word "source" would be made a link.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that where the link starts in your comment is where you have a `[` character in the comment (as a part of the regex).

This is a meaningful character in markdown, the start of link character.  You can escape it with a slash (`\`) to ensure that it's treated as a literal.

Below is that same comment with the escaped character, as a comment.  Here is the markdown for that comment:

```
This is roughly true, but the actual conditions are "(1)one-char String and this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()\[{^?*+\\", or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter." ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29))
```

(Note that adding line breaks can potentially also affect how the markdown is rendered, so I've not included any.)

Comment: This is roughly true, but the actual conditions are "(1)one-char String and this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()\[{^?*+\\", or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter." ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29))

Comment: 1) this does not explain why it would behave differently in comments than in the question, and 2) it really should be changed to lazy regex instead of greedy, right?

Comment: @eis 1) Markdown isn't really standardized; what documentation there is on it really leaves this particular behavior ambiguous.  But consistency within the site would be nice, sure.  2) I don't think that that would address the problem.  The parser sees a `[`, assumes that this is the start of a a linked text block, it sees a `]` later on immediately followed by a `(`, a link, and then a `)`.  It takes everything between the `[` and `]` and links it to the parenthesized link.  It'd need to be a non-greedy algorithm for it to skip the first `[` and try to find the one closest to the `]`.

Comment: 2) yeah. Anyway, IMO changing it would make sense, it does seem more logical to assume the closest `[` is the one related to the link.

Comment: @eis "why it would behave differently in comments than in the question" [Comments only support a subset of Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), so they're parsed differently. StackExchange's parser also adds some interesting quirks, such as requiring backslashes to escape backticks in inline code blocks (`\`I'm a backtick: \\`\``) instead of the standard multiple backticks (`\`\` I'm a backtick: \` \`\``).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot even if only subset is supported, I don't think there's a reason not to have questions and comments to work consistently in this regard

Comment: @eis At this point, there's probably a compelling reason in the form of "don't potentially break tons of existing comments". If I remember correctly, comments are formatted from Markdown on the fly, while questions and answers are cached as HTML.